# Adding Records from a table of search results in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webforms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I have a table of results that is representing a search of various social media sites.  The table contains a ton of things like images, descirption, name etc.

The user will have the option to click an 'add' button in on any element in the table and then that user will have that thing associated with their account.

I"m stuck on how to do this. Here is my workaround solution:

```
 <td> <%= link_to "Add", trackers_path( social_id: t.id.to_s), method: :post  %> </td>
```

I am able to post to the trackers path but am having two issues.

1. How do i nest the url_options so that strong parameters will only need one filter?  Right now they are coming through as a `params["social_id"]` and I would like to reference it using `params["trackers"]["social_id"]`
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you can send as trackers_path( trackers: { social_id: t.id.to_s})
But, really you should not call to trackers_path, you better define an add method, add that to the routes, later call it as add_trackers_path( social_id: t.id.to_s )

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, to put all your params into a single filter, you'll need to do something like this:

```
tracker_path(filters: { social_id: t.id.to_s } )
```

Alternatively, you could use a form to replicate this:

```
<%= form_tag tracker_path, method: :post do %>
   <%= text_field_tag "filters[:social_id]" %>
<% end %>
```